# How many arrows is an archer expected to fire by the end of the Tyranny of Dragons pair of adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, ammunition, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen, rise-of-tiamat

Tyranny of Dragons spans two supplements:

- Hoard of the Dragon Queen
- Rise of Tiamat

If an archer was expected to buy all of their arrows up front, what is a reasonable estimate of how many arrows they would need throughout the coarse of a full Tyranny of Dragons campaign?

Assume that we are not using the 50% arrow recovery rule and are instead using 0% arrow recovery.

This question was asked with the assumption of a standard party-size.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91391/discussion-on-question-by-axoren-how-many-arrows-is-an-archer-expected-to-fire-b).

Comment: This can be answered with decent specificity by someone familiar with this published campaign.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Very, very approximately: 3,000 \$\pm \$ 1,000

This would cost 150gp and weigh 150 lb. Except, they get half their arrows back if they search for them so, half of all that.

Assuming:

- the PCs start at level 1 and finish with just enough XP to get to level 16
- the number of encounters per level is as per my answer to [Why does the experience-to-next-level not change between some levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/why-does-the-experience-to-next-level-not-change-between-some-levels/62358#62358)
- The archer uses their bow for 4 rounds in each combat
- The archer always uses the bow even though there are encounters in the adventure where ranged attacks will be at disadvantage because the player will be in melee due to constrained battlefields
- The archer gets [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ExtraAttack) as a fighter
- All arrows are lost

Then:

[image]

Now, the 357 encounters is possibly on the high side but if you do all the side-quests and have a lot of random encounters, I can see you getting there.

Answer (score -3):

Well, you can probably figure a normal fight runs four to six turns, and a big fight or boss battle might run twice that long.  So multiply by the number of fights in the modules and the number of shots per turn, and you should be able to approximate it from there.

But there isn't a fixed number of fights in those modules. It depends on how your skills roll out, how long you take, what you choose to do, and a lot of other things. I don't think it's possible to even vaguely approximate how many combat-rounds there might be across both modules because it just really depends.

Comment: I haven't seen many combats last this long in my experience, though I have only played through the first part of the module