# Is there a mechanical disadvantage or taboo with creating an underaged character?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

Maybe I have overthought this before posting, but I have a nagging feeling that I might be missing a piece of mechanics or social taboo that addresses this topic.

I am interested in playing a character cursed with more power than they can control, learning to hone their gift and disprove the rumours that he's a monster. I can easily flavour the build as a Haunted One Wild Magic Sorcerer, but I also feel like casting him in an adolescent role (12 at the youngest) would help play a big part in building up both the complexity of his situation as well as the immaturity with which he tries to solve it... *eg. being more susceptible to peer pressure, not understanding if this new sensation of desire towards an NPC is a manifestation of his curse (attraction vs compulsion), and how he deals with balancing the want to be around the party and the fear that he'll hurt them.*

All that said, I also want to be mindful of any social taboos or mechanics that I might be stepping on the toes of. I haven't come across any piece of text as of late, but I thought I'd double-check with the community before solidifying this concept.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## It depends on the group and the campaign

D&D 5th Edition has no rules for starting ages, or any rules for ageing at all. See [Quadratic Wizard's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168678/48759) to a related question for a comparison to the rules from 3.5e. More specifically 5e simply states:

> You choose your character's age and the color of his or her hair, eyes, and skin. *(PHB p.121)*

Since the rules don't prevent it and there is zero mechanical impacts you absolutely *can* create an underaged character and play them successfully in campaign (I have done so but more on that later). What remains is to determine if you *should*.

### The Heroic Fantasy Stereotype

In my experience most rulebooks, adventure models and players assume  a cast of player characters that are approximately young adult in age. Something equivalent to 16-30 in human years once lifespans are accounted for. There are a lot of good reasons for this.

Characters in this age-group are perfect for the typically "heroes journey" type stories most campaigns tell to some degree. Physically capable of the heroic feats the campaign will require, but without the experience that wouldn't make sense for a low-level character. Sure sometimes you get the "grizzled veteran" or a late bloomer trying out adventuring later in life but these still fit the "adventure fantasy" stereotype.

Younger characters don't fit this stereotype, for both practical and thematic reasons. Other players will have expectations of the kind of scenes that will play out (e.g. drinking in a tavern after a successful mission, a steamy romance story, or a dark and menacing fight) or for the type of story that will be told and playing a child character may upset their expectations. Whether going against type is acceptable is for you and your group to decide, and is the sort of thing that should be discussed during a session 0.

### Campaign Expectations

A good session 0 sets up a mutual understanding of the campaign your are about to undertake. What themes and content the game will or won't entail and the kind of characters that would suit the narrative. If appropriate for your group it should also touch on boundary areas or topics that some players would find taboo. Some examples; use of explicit language at the table, level of sexual content acceptable (between character or npcs), what is ok to joke about during play, and the presence (or absence) of themes such as slavery, torture, sexual assault, racism, etc...

Once you have established which (if any) of these themes are going to be present in your game you and your group can decide if it is the kind of campaign where you would feel comfortable having a child as a PC.

If you are playing in a game about rescuing tortured and persecuted slaves while trying to sleep with every NPC with a pulse, you might decide this isn't the campaign for a child character. Conversely if playing a lighthearted quest to stop the evil King from banning all candy, playing a child might be the perfect character.

These are obviously some extreme examples and most campaigns will fall somewhere in-between. The point is that it is important for you to discuss it with your group ahead of time and identify if playing an underage character is appropriate for the campaign you are about to play.

### An anecdotal account

My last campaign as a player I played as a 15 year old Drow Druid. In our world that meant he was about the equivalent of a 12 year old human. My backstory was that I had run away from home in the underdark to follow the call of the forest (cliche druid stuff), before having a run in with another member of the party. This campaign contained a reasonable amount racism (due to my Drow heritage) and some dark themes but very little sexual or explicit content.

We had an extensive discussion about what the campaign would entail, including some back and forth with my DM about how dark the storyline may get and to ensure we were comfortable with it. Ultimately we decided that all the players were adults and capable of understanding that terrible things could happen to a fictional child of a fictional race in a fictional world and playing through that and giving them the opportunity for character growth was something we were happy to do at that table.

Your group and your campaign may be different, just know that it is absolutely possible to play a younger character, even in a relatively dark campaign.

### Playing young characters

For my group there was no mechanical impact for my character's age, and only minor roleplaying impacts. I never tried to be annoyingly naive or play up the childishness in a way that could be disruptive to the game, playing a character with 20 wisdom in a "wise beyond his years" type might have contributed to that but I still believe it is the best way to play a young character. Don't try to overplay the child aspect and fall into "main character" or "my guy" syndromes.

Unless you are in a scenario where the character's age is relevant to the scene (e.g. buying drinks at a bar) play them as you would any other character. Physical stats are physical stats and you don't need to make up an explanation for why your 13 year old has 18 strength any more than you do for while the wizard can cast fireballs. Its just the way the game works.

Sure your stats and abilities may not be typical for a character of your age, but neither are any of the older PCs in the party. The point of being a PC is that your are somehow exceptional, every PC is more powerful in some way than logical would state they have any right to be. That's what separates the heroes and adventures from the common folk. Build some homebrew mechanical impact if you wish, but I would advise against it. Particularly if it is only a penalty, at least balance it out with some of the advantages of youth. Whatever you do, don't punish the player with less fun mechanics because they wanted to play an original character.

### Conclusion

If a player has a strong idea for a young character, that character suits the campaign and all players are comfortable with a child character there is no reason to stop them from playing one. Go ahead and have a whole party of children if that's what the campaign calls for.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth response. I was aiming more for a Lone Wolf and Cub trope approach with this character, so exposure to darker or more mature scenes happening around him might actually work out for the better. That said, your point about playing young characters is one I'll have to take to heart as I build them. Thank you.

Comment: In particular, I know a common no-go line for players (which is something that should be covered for everyone in a session 0) is *harm to children*. If you're playing a literal child, who is going to be in combat regularly, some of the other players (or even the DM) may legitimately be uncomfortable with that idea for any game they are going to participate in. So the player should be prepared to go with some other idea, with no hard feelings.

Comment: Speaking as an older father of two little ones, if you _are_ wanting to have mechanical impacts, one of the advantages of the very young is how amazingly fast they heal. I feel the disadvantages are more obvious.

Answer (score 4):

### What is acceptable in play depends on your group

The rules have no restriction on age. Page 121, *PHB*:

> **You choose your character’s age** and the color of his or her hair, eyes, and skin.

There is no further limitation, rules wise.

What is acceptable or not to your fellow players varies from table to table and only they can tell you. **Talk with them** about your idea before play, maybe in a session 0 if you have one.

For example, in my playgroup, this would be entirely unproblematic. In [Shivers's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/207763/75095) it would be not acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be more taboo along the lines of requesting a Repeating Shot Seige Lazer Gun to a medieval campaign, but knowing that it's only a matter of preference really settles my concerns. I'll make sure to address this with them.

Comment: > _"Repeating Shot Seige Lazer Gun"_

Fun fact. One party I DM for got to be on receiving end of one of those when they decided to assist with siege of a city, which wouldn't give them access to their library. That kind of things tend to happen when the head engineer of the city is an expy of Archimedes.